# Which kind of img data is lost when storing a file in a variable first?

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

I want to send an Email with PHPMailer and use an HTML template using:

```
$mail->msgHTML()
```

When using:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('./contents.html'), __DIR__);
```

Everything works as expected, and the email contains the image, **without** attaching it.
But if I store the file contents in a variable like so:

```
$body = file_get_contents('./contents.html');
$mail->msgHTML($body);
```

the image data gets lost.
Why is my image not included in the sent email when reading file contents into a variable first?
-OR- What kind (part) of data is lost?
Why do I have to send it as an Attachment to get it working?

HTML code for reference:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; color:#929292; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif;">
<img src="./logo_nav.png" alt="" sizes="" srcset="">
</td>
```

Comment: why did you omit `__DIR__` argument in second example?

Comment: In an email you can't just reference an image, you must attach it as well.

Comment: @tadman So, that would mean that PHPMailer attaches the ing "under the hood" when passing the HTML document directly?

Comment: It's possible, it'd have to if that image actually works in an email. Worth checking the documentation or the final email source.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [phpmailer docs](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_msgHTML), you need to include the basedir parameter:

> If you don't provide a $basedir, relative paths will be left untouched (and thus probably break in email)

Once you do this, images will be inlined automatically.  If you call it with `__DIR__`, it should work:

```
$mail->msgHTML($body, __DIR__);
```

Comment: Thanks! That must've slipped through while digging. But unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: Is it still working when you call file_get_contents() inside msgHTML()?  It shouldn't make any difference, as file_get_contents() returns a string on success (or false on failure).  Since it's possible for it to fail, I'd check that `$body !== false`.

Comment: Make sure that the path to the HTML file and the path to the basedir are both accurate.  `__DIR__` is the path to the script you're executing and may not be the path to the content you're reading.